# Codeigniter get_where() function some of conditions are not working

Tags: codeigniter

In the  get_all_staff(), I would like to get the company's staffs list based on the cnditions i have defined, but for example 'role !='=>'Management Office', is not working , and if I change its place in the code , it would works but the other condition will not work, what I am trying to say is all the syntax are correct, but all the conditions are not working in the same tiem.

```
public function get_all_staff($company_name)
{
    //  $query = $this->db->get_where('user_login', array('company_name' => $company_name,'role !='=>'Manager','delete_flag'=>0,'role !='=>'Management Office' , 'role !='=>'Admin'));

    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_login', array('company_name' => $company_name,'role !='=>'Management Office','role !='=>'Manager','delete_flag'=>0 ,'role!='=>'Admin'));
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this.

```
public function get_all_staff($company_name)
{
    $this->db->where('company_name', $company_name);
    $this->db->where('role !=', 'Management Office');
    $this->db->where('role !=', 'Manage');
    $this->db->where('role !=', 'Admin');
    $this->db->where('delete_flag', '0');
    
    return $this->db->get('user_login')->result_array();
    //if there is only one row then do it
    // return $this->db->get('user_login')->row_array();
}
```